# Can I search through and compare commonly named variables in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a list of about 30 variables, all named something like test_1, test_2, test_3, etc. I need to check if the values are all the same, and typically do so by exporting to excel and using an if statement comparing the min value to the max (i.e. if the min=max then all the values are the same).

Is there a way I can do this right in SPSS without having to export? It seems inefficient to compare if test_1=test_2 and test_2=test_3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a hack, but it get's the job done: can calculate the standard deviation of all your variables:

```
compute sd_test=SD(test_1, test_2, ..., test_n).
EXECUTE.
```

`sd_test=0` for records where all `test_i` variables are equal.

Comment: of course also this would work `compute allsame=min(test_1 to test_30)=max(test_1 to test_30)` but I love the SD hack for shorter code ;)